# Hibernate exception (one-to-many relashipship): reference to unknown entity

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using Hibernate.

Say, one `Person` can only have one `Book`. But each `Book` could be reserved by **multiple** `Person`s.

I am implementing this relationship, and I am using a joint table *person_book* for this relationship.

**Here is what I did :**

`Person` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
   private int pid;
   private Book book;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinTable(name="person_book",
             joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="pid")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="bid")})
   public Book getBook() {
    return book;
   }

   public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
   }

   //Setter & Getter for pid 
   ...
}
```

`Book` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
   private int bid;
   private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinTable(name="person_book",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="bid")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="pid")})
  public Set<Person> getPersons() {
     return persons;
  }

  public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
    this.persons = persons;
  }

  //Setter & Getter for bid
  ...
}
```

In hibernate configuration I have:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    ...
    <mapping class="com.my.db.model.Person" />
    <mapping class="com.my.db.model.Book" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I start my tomecat , I constantly get the following Hibernate exception:

```
 org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.my.db.model.Person.book references an unknown entity: com.my.db.model.Book
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1557)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1478)
```

It complains that the Book is an unknown entity. Why? Where did I do wrongly ? I feel Most likely the problem is about the hibernate annotations...

(Please don't suggest me to not to use join table. Thanks.)

Comment: `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` relations can be done without a join table, try it without that annotation, maybe that's the problem

Comment: I also wonder why there is a hibernate configuration file when JPA is used. There is a valid persistence.xml file to setup a persistence context and a JPA EntityManager is used to do the querying right?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at your stacktrace, you will see

```
Error :org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.my.db.model.Person.book references an unknown entity: com.my.db.model.Book
```

So this field

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinTable(name="person_book",
             joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="pid")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="bid")})
   public Book getBook() {
    return book;
   }
```

is causing the problem. `@ManyToOne` has a paramater `targetEntity` which says:

```
(Optional) The entity class that is the target of the association. Defaults to the type of the field or property that stores the association.
```

thus Update Your Table Structure as

***Table Structure***

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
   KEY `fk_book_id` 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_book_id`) REFERENCES `book` (`id`)   
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

***Entity Clases***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
   private int pid;
   private Book book;

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_book_id", nullable = false)
  public Book getBook() {
    return book;
  }

  //Setter & Getter for pid 
   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
   private int bid;
   private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
  public Set<Person> getPersons() {
     return persons;
  }

  //Setter & Getter for bid
  ...
}
```

hope this will solve your problem